# Jmeter- soap-xml sampler request

Tags: jmeter, rpc

I am using jmeter, I am very new to it and have min programming background.
I am currently using 2 sampler: a) soap Request b) soap xml rpc request.

Uisng the soap request sampler, I can easily load the wsdl file and continue my testing.
RESPONSE
But unable to  do so with 'soap xml rpc request' sampler
the message I am getting here is 
a:ActionNotSupportedThe message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
SAMPLER RESULT
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-09-27 15:03:07 BST
Load time: 7
Latency: 7
Size in bytes: 698
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 698
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 698
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 14:03:07 GMT
Connection: close

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/xml; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8

Comment: Could you show your configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be simple - just uncheck the 'Send SOAP Action" checkbox in SOAP/XML-RPC request and try again